# How many maximum height AVL trees given height?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I am having some trouble finding a recursive formula for finding the number of maximum height AVL trees of height h. Height 0 has 1, height 1 has 2, height 2 has 4, height 3 has 8, etc. is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let look at this problem from another point of view.

Instead of maximum height for a given count of nodes, let find the minimum number of nodes for a given height. For this problem, we have this recursive function: `n(h) = n(h-1) + n(h-2) + 1` because you need at least `n(h-1)` nodes in right subtree and `n(h-2)` nodes in left subtree and one node for root.

[image: AVL Tree]
(image and more complete explanation [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Trees/AVL-height.html)).

With that in mind, you have to find an `h` such that `n(h) < n < n(h+1)` where n is your given number of nodes.

By the way the short answer is `h < 2log(n) + 2`

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of nodes `n` in AVL tree of height `h` is `n = 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^(h-1) = 2^h - 1` (each node except the root has both children, meaning that each level has twice more nodes than the previous one). That gives the formula of height `h` in terms of number of nodes `n` as: `h = log(n + 1)`.